# Make UIView scrollable and zoomable

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4, iosdeployment

I'm trying to make a UIView scrollable and zoomable, I embedded in a scroll view and set its delegate but it does not work.

I'd like that "selectCountries" UIView can be scrolled and zoomed in and out like an image or similar.

How can achieve this result?

Here is what I've done so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var selectCountries: VTCSelectCountryView!
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .clear

        self.selectCountries?.selectedCountries = ["ITA","USA","GBR","FRA"]
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews(){
           super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
           scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
           // scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height+60)

       }

    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.selectCountries
    }
}
```

EDIT 1: I tried by adding the values written in the comments below but it still does not zoom and scroll the view.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var selectCountries: VTCSelectCountryView!
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .clear

        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0

        scrollView.bounces = true
        scrollView.bouncesZoom = true
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: selectCountries.frame.size.width, height: selectCountries.frame.size.height)
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true

        self.selectCountries?.selectedCountries = ["ITA","USA","GBR","FRA"]
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews(){
           super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
           scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
           // scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height+60)
       }

    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.selectCountries
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: Here is a screenshot of the storyboard

[image: Storyboard-Scrollview_screenshot]

Comment: @AnreaMaps Can you please share your user interface of ViewController class?

Comment: @HardikS I added a screenshot

Comment: why you have given bottom constraints of select countries `UIView` to `UITextField` and `UIScrollView` both? Remove unnecessary bottom constraints of `UIView`  to  `UIScrollVIew` and let me know it is working or not.

Comment: @HardikS I tried it but it still does not work, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to also set the minimum and maximum zoom scale of `UIScrollView`

Set zoom scale in your `viewDidLoad()` method

```
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

set **ZoomScale** and add subview's **contentsize** in your `viewDidLoad()`

```
    scrollview.maximumZoomScale = 4
    scrollview.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollview.bounces = true
    scrollview.bouncesZoom = true
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSize(width: imagerepoart.frame.size.width, height: imagerepoart.frame.size.height)
    scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
    scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
```

Comment: please check scrollview's constraint are proper or not.